# Creating a "horizontal" table in HTML(with bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to achieve this design:
[image: horizontal table with a picture attached]

As you can see, instead of having columns with headers, i have rows, where the first "value" is actually the header.

I need the HTML layout to be responsive and tidy for all resolutions. Also, i would appreciate it much, if someone advises me how to keep picture on the right, more or less aligned with the "table"(of course, in small resolutions i would make the picture take an entire Bootstrap row)

Is there any "generic" way to achieve this? By generic i mean something that doesn't require meticulous CSS and unnecessary media queries.

I'm working with Bootstrap 3.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: Agreed. Right now looks like you are looking for a lot of solutions. Image on the right is different problem all together. Headers on the side is achievable with a simple table.

Answer (score -4):

Looks like this is what you are looking for:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-md-6"> 
    This will be the left side
    <div class="row"> First Row</div>
    <div class="row"> Third Row</div>
    <div class="row"> Fourth Row</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6"> 
    This will be the right side
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can accomplish this with [bootstrap tables](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-tables.php). The left column will hold the table and the right column will hold the image.

See the snippet: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Vgnb3

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Row</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Carter</td>
        <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Parker</td>
        <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Rambo</td>
        <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/650x150"
</div>
```

Comment: But it's still just a regular table :D

Comment: Jen, it wasn't me who downvoted you. There are very judgmental people in stackoverflow, just looking for someone to downvote. I ain't one of them. Notice that i my self was downvoted, god knows what for.