# Razor Pages horizontal Table

Tags: asp.net-core, html-table, datagrid, data-visualization, razor-pages

Good morning,

I am developing my Web Application using **.Net Core 3.1** and **Razor Pages**.

In my application I need to display a large amount of data on a grid and would therefor like to **rotate** a standard **grid 90 degrees**. I would like to obtain something like the "Horizontal Scroll" of this [blog post](https://uxdesign.cc/design-better-data-tables-4ecc99d23356) but instead of just scrolling horizontally I would likle to move the headers to the side and, as mentioned above, rotate the entire grid fields.

I can't find any API that suites my needs though. Does anyone have suggestions on something I could try? I wouldn't want to have to build the entire grid myself (with all the paging, filtering and ordering logic). I am open for alternative solutions as well!!

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems more like an HTML question, and does not really relate to Razor Pages.  Here are a couple of examples of horizontal scrolling HTML tables:

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/scroll/#datatable-horizontal-scroll

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html

Comment: Hello Shawn, first of all thak you for your answer. I already gave a look at these options but they propose horizontal scrolling not rotating the entire table 90 degreese (my goal is to have the header on the left and the fields distributed from top to bottom to the right of said header). Anyhow yes, I am looking for a table controller that gives me these functionalities (together with columnsizing, sorting, ecc).

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871458/creating-a-horizontal-table-in-htmlwith-bootstrap) but with a functioning table instead of a picture to the right.

Answer (score 1):

> You said you need to display `a large amount of data`, I think the
>   design you currently want is not suitable for the display of a large
>   amount of data.

Because if the title is on the left, then only one data can be displayed on each page, and each page needs to load the title, which will lead to great **redundancy**.

If you just want to display beautiful because of too many columns, I suggest you use the  **`responsive`** property in `jQuery datatable`, which can dynamically display the number of columns according to your current page width, and collapse or display the extra columns.

You can refer to [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/column-control.html).

Comment: Thank you, this is definetly a better alternative!